# unable to retrieve sql data to use in another query

Tags: php, html, sql, session, mysqli

I'm struggeling with a problem and maybe someone could help me :)

in the first query I want to sent data to the first table which generates a id for me, at the second quary I want to retrieve that id made by the first quary, on the 3th quary I want to use that id to insert other data in a second table with the same id as the first table.

My question is this: everything is getting inserted fine except the $id, am I missing something?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //declaratie sessie variabelen
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $voornaam = $_SESSION['voornaam'];
    $achternaam = $_SESSION['achternaam'];
    $firma = $_SESSION['firma'];

    //database configuratie file
    require('dbconfig.php');

    //Declaratie post variabelen
    $ticnaam = $_POST['ticket_naam'];
    $ticonderwerp = $_POST['ticket_onderwerp'];
    $ticassign = $_POST['ticket_voor'];
    $bericht = $_POST['bericht'];

    //proccesing


    //procces first quary
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tickets` 
                        (`naam`, `onderwerp`, `maker`) 
                VALUES ('$ticnaam', '$ticonderwerp', '$username')";

    //retrieves the generated new id from the quary above
    $sql2 = "SELECT id FROM tickets where onderwerp='$ticonderwerp' AND naam = '$ticnaam';";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2);
    $id = mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


    //insertes the id into another quary
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO `berichten` 
                        (`id`, `text`, `voornaam`,`achternaam`,`firma`) 
                VALUES ('$id', '$bericht', '$voornaam',
                        '$achternaam','$firma')";

    //sql3 ok? user can continu
    if($mysqli->query($sql3) == TRUE) {
        require('email_na_ticketaanmaak.php')
?>
<script>alert('nieuw ticket is gemaakt');</script>
<?php
        require('../procces_files/email_na_ticketaanmaak.php');
        header('Location: ../home/index.php');
    }else{
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
    }
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: You need `mysqli::$insert_id` [See manual page here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: For one, you never executed the INSERT query for `$sql`.

Comment: Use prepared statements for preventing SQL injections.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Oh yea missed that, I need to stop for High Tea

Comment: @RiggsFolly Heh, it's normal to be preoccupied in these trying times.

Comment: Unrelated but seriously ...please read up on PDO or at least use prepared statements to protect your SQL queries!

Comment: yea sorry :) iknow that the code isn't that secure yet, i want to do the security after the application is complete :)

Comment: _i want to do the security after the application is complete_ Yea right, that of course wont happen.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property of the mysqli object called `$insert_id` that will return you the `id` of the newly inserted row if the `id` column is an AutoIncrement column.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //database configuratie file
    require('dbconfig.php');

    // process first query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tickets` 
                    (`naam`, `onderwerp`, `maker`) VALUES (?,?,?)";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['ticket_naam'],
                            $_POST['ticket_onderwerp'],
                            $_SESSION['username']);
    $stmt->execute();

    // retrieves the generated new id from the query above
    $new_id = $mysqli->insert_id;

    // inserts the id into another query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `berichten` 
                        (`id`, `text`, `voornaam`,`achternaam`,`firma`) 
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('isss', $new_id,
                                $_POST['bericht'],
                                $_SESSION['voornaam'],
                                $_SESSION['achternaam'],
                                $_SESSION['firma']);
    $res = $stmt->execute();
    if ($res) {
        require('email_na_ticketaanmaak.php')
        require('../procces_files/email_na_ticketaanmaak.php');
        header('Location: ../home/index.php');
    }else{
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
    }
?>
```

If you are going to redirect to another page using

```
header('Location: ../home/index.php');
```

there is no point sending this back to the page you were on, as you will never see it.

```
<script>alert('nieuw ticket is gemaakt');</script>
```

> Also Your script was open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

So I changed the code a little to use parameterised, prepared and bound queries.